# Weird styling on New Products block in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: css, magento

I inserted a New Products block on my homepage, but the add to cart button, add to wishlist, & add to compare are overlapping the product title that is below the image...any idea where I can fix this? I've been messing with scss files and using compass to compile them into the css, but I don't know what I could've done to cause this.

Also for some reason it's styling the title to have bullet points?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- "I've been messing with scss files and using compass to compile them into the css"
- "I don't know what I could've done to cause this"
- "Any idea where I can fix this"

Perhaps I'm missing something, but how about you undo you changes to the scss files and recompile them.  Also, try downloading a fresh version of Magento 1.92 and comparing the contents of the file you're editing with `diff`.  There's literally an unlimited number of things you could have done that would change the styles on the page.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I was hoping someone might know where the styling for this particular element lies or what it is labeled as in the style sheets.